# how to read data in rich content files using NSFilehandler

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pdf

This is my swift code simplified:

```
func readContent(url:NSURL!){




    do {
        let file: NSFileHandle? = try NSFileHandle(forReadingFromURL: url)
        if (file  != nil){
            file?.seekToFileOffset(10)
           let content=file!.readDataOfLength(5)


            print(String(data: content, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding))

            file!.closeFile()


        }

                }catch {


    }



}
```

I am building a file reader, that could read text files and pdfs. I am using NSFileHandler because I need to keep track of the position where the reading is happening.

I am able to read text files without a problem. However with pdfs I am having two problems:

1. How do I get the type of encoding used to encore the pdf?     *NSASCIIStringEncoding* for instance does not work fine with text file but not with the pdf file. I am getting strange characters. I imaging that there is a way to detect the encoding. I have been following https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html and I haven't found anything addressing this issue on stack overflow.
2. Given the fact that pdfs may contain text, images and videos how do I identify these contents while reading.. I read that magic numbers might do it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files but I read that there are not advisable http://www.techrepublic.com/article/avoid-using-magic-numbers-and-string-literals-in-your-code/. In addition I have not yet found a guide on how to use them.

please note that it is important for me to keep track of the Offset while reading.

Comment: PDF is a structured file format with objects, arrays, dictionaries etc. The texts themselves are can be in various encodings and are usually compressed. On top of that, the objects can be compressed as well. You cannot just read the entire file using "some encoding" and then expect to find the text content. You have to read and implement the PDF file format. It is doable, but not a simple task (the PDF 1.7 specification http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf has more than 1000 pages). – You might be better off by finding a open source PDF library.

Comment: Btw, *"don't use magic numbers in your code"* has nothing to do with "magic numbers" identifying a file format.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. is there any free library that could do it.. I guess reading the 1000 pages book is good for a long term, which I will do but a library will be welcome.

Comment: I have seen some, but not used any, so I cannot recommend anything.

Comment: alright .. I am still doing some research on it .. thanks again

Comment: Have you looked at PDFKit? It may give you what you need.